# How can I view history in terminal for specific date?

Tags: command-line, bash, date, history

How can I view the terminal history for a specific date?

For example today is 4-apr and I want to view the history of 31-mar

Answer (score 30):

You can set the `history` format to include the date using the following:

```
HISTTIMEFORMAT="%d/%m/%y %T "
```

Then filter for a specific date using `grep`:

```
history | grep "31/03"
```

---

> More info:
>
> - Note From @muru and @Kamil- HISTTIMEFORMAT should already have been set during this period, or bash will just use today's date
> - [Bash Man](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-HISTTIMEFORMAT) - **HISTTIMEFORMAT**
> - [nixCraft - Bash History - Display Date and Time](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-bash-history-display-date-time/)

Comment: Note that `HISTTIMEFORMAT` should already have been set during this period, or bash will just use today's date.

Comment: @Kamil - thanks for the message about HISTTIMEFORMAT!

Comment: @kulwinder1986 - if I've answered your question please [accept](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer) / [up-vote](http://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/vote-up) my answer.